# Differentiate the Function: $g(y)=ln\frac{(2y+1)^5}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus

$g(y)=ln\frac{(2y+1)^5}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}$

$g(y)= ln(2y+1)^5-ln\sqrt{y^2-1}$

g'(y)=$\frac{5(2y+1)^4\cdot (2)}{(2y+1)^5}-\frac{2(y^2+1)(2y)}{(y^2+1)^2}$

At this point I can cancel the (2y+1) from the numerator and denominator of the first rational equation and from the second rational equation $(y^2+1)$. However, how would I get $\frac{y}{y^2+1}$ my answer is

$g'(y)=\frac{10}{(2y+1)}-\frac{4y}{y^2+1)^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$g=\log\frac{(2y+1)^5}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}=5\log(2y+1)-\frac 12 \log(y^2+1)$$ $$g'=5 \frac 2{2y+1}-\frac 12 \frac {2y}{y^2+1}=\frac {10}{2y+1}-\frac {y}{y^2+1}=\frac{8 y^2-y+10}{(2y+1)(y^2+1)}$$

Comment: Claude Leibovici - I am confused when it comes to finding the derivative. If we use this formula $\frac{d}{dx}[ln g(x)]=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$ I got $\frac{5(2y+1)\cdot (2)}{(2y+1)^5}-\frac{\frac{1}{2}(y^2+1)(2y)}{(y^2+1)^-\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: You have $g= \text{something}$ and not $\log(g)=\text{something}$

Comment: I don't follow what you mean. Can you point out where in my work I am making a mistake when it comes to the formula I am using?

Comment: Use the rules of logarithms first to make  life easier. The error is in the second term because you did not take into account the square root.

Comment: I see. I made $^2$  instead of $^\frac {1}{2}$

Comment: Yes, my friend !

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Write

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\log \sqrt{y^2+1}\right)=\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac12\log (y^2+1)\right)=\frac12\left(\frac{2y}{y^2+1}\right)$$

To address the OP's comment, here $g(y)=y^2+1$ and $g'(y)=2y$.

Comment: I am using this formula $\frac{d}{dx}[ln g(x)]=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$

Comment: @SunnyBlack:  if you are using that formula, you are getting confused with $g(x)$   Given you have $g(x)=\ln h(x)$, then $g'(x)=\frac {h'(x)}{h)x)}$

Comment: I don't follow what you mean. Can you show me?

Comment: @SunnyBlack I added a note to help explain.  There was one simplification made, namely $\log (y^2+1)^{1/2}=\frac12\log (y^2+1)$