# Differentiate the function: $f(u)=\frac{u}{1+\ln u}$

Tags: calculus

$f(u)=\frac{u}{1+\ln u}$

$=\ln u-\ln 1+\ln u$

=$\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{u}$

=$\frac{1-u+1}{u^2}\ =-\frac{u}{u^2}-\frac{1}{u}$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Apply $(\frac u v)'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$ The second line looks very strange : how did you make it ?

Comment: To be honest, none of the steps you have made is correct.

Comment: Indeed, *every single step* in this calculation is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\\\frac{d}{du}\frac{g(u)}{h(u)} &= \frac{g'(u)h(u)-g(u)h'(u)}{h(u)^2}\ \ \ (1)
\\\frac{d}{du}\frac{u}{1+\ln(u)} &= \frac{1*(1+\ln(u))-u*(0+\frac{1}{u})}{(1+\ln(u))^2}
\\\\\frac{d}{du}\frac{u}{1+\ln(u)} &= \frac{\ln(u)}{(1+\ln(u))^2}
\end{align*}
$$

$(1)$ is the so called quotinent rule, which is useful in this situation, but you could also apply chain rule with a bit of acrobatics, if you're more familiar with it.

Comment: Can you explain this problem to me also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349237/differentiate-the-function-gy-ln-frac2y15-sqrty21 Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Claude pointed out, use the quotient rule. Where (u)'=1 and (1+ln(u))'=1/u, and (u/v)'=(u'v-v'u)/v^2.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to check your answer is to graph the numeric derivative of the original function and your supposed derivative. If your answer is correct, the graphs should be practically identical. (You can use a graphing calculator, graphing software, or Desmos online to do the graphing.) Here are the graphs for your problem. (My graphing software requires me to change the independent variable to $x$ rather than the $u$ that you used.)

[image]

You can see that the graphs are not the same, so your answer is not correct.

As others have already pointed out, use the quotient rule on the original function to get a correct answer. Try it, and if you cannot finish let us know how far you got and we'll try to help you more.